# Cell borders in excel with PHP

Tags: php, excel

I'm using clean php to draw excel table:

```
$xls .= "Field\t\Cell1\t\Cell2\tCell3\r\n"
$xls .= chr(hexdec('FF')) . chr(hexdec('FE')) . $xls; //headers
echo $xls;
```

Is there any way to draw cell borders without using excel-library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to output an Excel file with almostly everything possible in Excel, you should use the following easy to use set of PHP classes:

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Excel has the knowledge to work with plain HTML tables. This will generate a warning from excel, but if you continue, it will show a table with border/colors/etc.

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
?>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
  <td style='background-color:#f00;'>header</td>
  <td style='background-color:#f00;'>header</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't control formatting in a CSV file.

Excel accepts a multitude of formats though, so if you don't feel like breaking out [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), you could create a [SpreadsheetML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb226687%28v=office.11%29.aspx) file instead. It's a format quite similar to html and you can control a lot of formatting in there.